# Will C++ throw with no arguments work inside another frame to rethrow an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, rethrow

If I have a code like the following:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (...) {
  noteError();
}

void noteError() {
  try {
    throw;
  } catch (std::exception &err) {
    std::cerr << "Note known error here: " << err.what();
  } catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "Note unknown error here.";
  }
  throw;
}
```

Will the original exceptions get thrown from both places inside the lower frame of noteError()?

Comment: Try it and see?  My suspicion is that it won't even compile but I detest exceptions so don't actually know.

Comment: @Dash, "try it and see" doesn't always yield a valid and confident answer. Maybe it's undefined behavior, and trying it merely proves that it works on your machine and nowhere else. Or, if it fails, maybe it's due to a compiler bug that failed to implement that particular aspect of the standard.

Comment: @Rob good point, thanks.  "Try it and see on every compiler you can find, and then add the Comeau online compiler to the front of that list"?  :)

Comment: @Dash: No, the only way to answer this question is to cite an authoritative source such as the standard. It is very hard to prove that no data corruption results from a particular instance of misbehavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording in the standard (§15.1/2) is (emphasis mine):

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the *nearest handler with a matching type* (15.3); “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement, ctor-initializer, or function-body *following the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.*

When has a try block "exited"? According to the grammar (§15/1), try blocks end with a *sequence* of handlers, so the block ends when the last handler ends. In other words:

```
try // <- start of try block
{
}
catch (whatever) // <- first handler
{
}
// ... more handlers
catch (whatever_again) // <- last handler
{
} // <- end of try block
```

So yes, your code is fine. When re-thrown, the nearest try block has a matching handler (namely `catch (...)`), so that handler is entered.

Comment: I've extended the question in a way which I still think works, but could you please confirm that a second throw will also work.

Comment: @William: As soon as you put a semicolon after `throw`. :) [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474429/does-throw-inside-a-catch-ellipsis-rethrow-the-original-error/2474436#2474436) might be of interest.

Answer (score 6):

Your original code was fine. You caught different exception types and called a function that would log a message and rethrow. The `throw` statement is not required to appear directly inside the corresponding `catch` block. If you call one of those "note" functions and you're *not* currently handling an exception, though, then your program will call `terminate()`.

Your new code is also fine. It's OK to catch everything and then call another function that rethrows to go to a more specific handler. That's [the *exception dispatcher* idiom described in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9). It looks a little peculiar to rethrow the exception *after* the dispatching block has finished, but if that same `throw` statement had occurred after `noteError` returned (inside the original `catch` block) instead of where it is now, then it would be perfectly ordinary; it's demonstrated in the standard, §15.1/6.