# Regarding throw statement followed by semicolon mark

Tags: c++, exception

In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void CleanCity(){
    try{
        throw "Garbage";
    }
    catch(const char *){
        cout << "Throw in Dustbin";
        throw;
    }
}
int main(){
    cout << "CleanCity mission starts";
    try{
        CleanCity();
    }
    catch(const char *){
        cout << "City Cleaned";
    }
    cout << "Well Done";
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell what the line throw ; does and how does this code print "City Cleaned". I also observed that if I remove throw ; then the program does not print "City Cleaned", but I can't get the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @oveofprogramming It retranslates the exception generated in the try block of the function.

Comment: @GBlodgett that link title seems right, but that question is about `throw;` outside of a `catch`.

Comment: I'm glad I read that one instead of reflexively dupe-hammering because of an excellent title.

Comment: Or this [Does throw inside a catch ellipsis (…) rethrow the original error in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474429/does-throw-inside-a-catch-ellipsis-rethrow-the-original-error-in-c)