# How do you substitute multiple lines of cpp code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a try-catch with multiple catch-statements. The catch-statments are about 30 lines of code. Many functions have the same catch-statements.
I would like to replace them with a single line of code (which would be defined somewhere, like a macro). Is this possbile with c++ / Microsoft Visual Studio?

```
try {...}
<INSERT SINGLE LINE OF CODE HERE>
```

Instead of:

```
try {...}
catch (HRESULT hr) {...}
catch (std::exception & e) {...}
catch (LPCWSTR e) {...}
catch (...) {...}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I abstract out a repeating try catch pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561659/how-can-i-abstract-out-a-repeating-try-catch-pattern-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Interesting, but not quite what I was looking for. I simply want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong about a function?

```
void common_handler() { /* handle common */ }

try {...}
catch (HRESULT hr)
{
    common_handler();
    // handle specific
}
catch (std::exception & e)
{
    common_handler();
    // handle specific
}
catch (LPCWSTR e)
{
    common_handler();
    // handle specific
}
catch (...)
{
    common_handler();
    // handle specific
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to get rid of al the catch statements too and not only the bodies.

Comment: Yes, I just want to get rid of all the catch statements. For the simple reason of making the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Learn to define functions (perhaps `static inline` ones) or macros, that is use wisely the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Take inspiration from several of the many [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) C++ projects on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com) or elsewhere.

Regarding the choice of your C++ compiler and your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor), consider alternatives. Such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) for the C++ compiler, [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) for the editor, and perhaps [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation). I also recommend using [git](https://git-scm.com/) as your version control.

I even recommend trying some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](https://debian.org/)), since they are extremely developer friendly and contains a lot of examples of open source C++ code (in particular [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)  or [fish](https://fishshell.com/) or [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/)). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24109/841108).

> How do you substitute multiple lines of cpp code?

A possibility is of course to *generate* some C++ code with another program (your own small C++ [metaprogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), a [Python](https://python.org/) script, a [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) one, etc...) then `#include` that generated C++ file. Look inside [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) for an example (work in progress). Or look inside [Qt](https://qt.io/) and its [moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) : they all generate C++ code.